# como puedo evitar que se recarge despues de mandar un dato a un array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Cómo puedo evitar que se recargue cada vez que guardo un dato, ya que por lo mismo que se recarga no me deja ver si se aguardan los datos. Nada mas aparece rápido y el número y desaparece y no se ve en la lista los datos. Acá si los mete en la lista como debe de ser.

Intente hacerlo con jquery pero al parecer no lo apliqué bien

```js
   const agregarVar = document.querySelector('#añadir');

 

    var arrayinput = [];

     agregarVar.addEventListener('click', function() {

    const inputAgregarVar = document.querySelector('#inputventa');
    if (inputAgregarVar.value == '') {

        inputventa.focus();
    } else {
        arrayinput.push(inputAgregarVar.value)
        inputAgregarVar.value = '';
        inputAgregarVar.focus();

        mostrar(arrayinput);

   
       }
   });
 
   function mostrar(arrayinput) {
       var listaUlVar = document.querySelector('#lista');
       listaUlVar.innerHTML = '';
       for (i of arrayinput) {
        var listaLi = document.createElement('li');
        listaLi.innerText = i;
        listaUlVar.appendChild(listaLi);

        console.log(i);

      }
  }
```

```html
   <input type="text" class="inputcolor " name="" id="inputventa">
                  <button type="submit" id="añadir" class="btn btn-color ">Añadir</button>
                 <button type="submit" id="Terminar" class="btn btn-color">Terminar</button>
                     

                        <ul id="lista"> </ul>
```

Comment: Yo no veo nada que se recargue ahí. Si se recarga tu página debe ser por otra cosa, no por esa función.

Comment: pues en todos los navegadores que he probado se actualiza ya lo cambie de carperta y quite muchas cosas que tenia demas y sigue igual

Comment: Pues lo que has puesto aquí está correcto. Espero que otro pueda ayudarte, porque yo no veo absolutamente nada funcionando mal en tu código. Podrías hacerlo añadiendo un "li" nuevo en vez de borrar y añadirlos todos de cada vez, pero por lo demás... funciona

Comment: Pues lo dicho por @Benito-B yo veo que el código trabaja, sería de mucha ayuda revises la pregunta nuevamente y edites agregando algún detalle que por ahi se te haya pasado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes parar que se envie el formulario cuando le das click en el btn de añadir.

```
<input type="text" class="inputcolor " name="" id="inputventa">
<button type="submit" id="añadir" class="btn btn-color ">Añadir</button>
<button type="submit" id="Terminar" class="btn btn-color">Terminar</button>
                     

<ul id="lista"> </ul>

<script>
$("#añadir").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // llamar a mis funciones para anadir datos de JS
}); 
</script>
```

Si lo que deseas o el motivo por el que se recarga no es formulario, nos comentas.

Comment: Vaya, no me había fijado en el type... en vez de todo eso es más fácil declarar el botón como type="button" y ya no hace un submit, no hay necesidad de pararlo